# How can I decide whether a file can be opened in Vim or not?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, fzf

I want to make a script with FZF (Fuzzy Finder) and I want to show only those file which can be opened with Vim. So, I don't want to list mp4, jpg, pdf etc files in FZF.

So, is there any way to decide whether a file can be opened in Vim or not?

Comment: Technically, vim can open any file... it just may not be useful. That said, have a look at the wildignore setting. If you can place reasonable restrictions on the kinds of files to exclude, something might be possible.

Comment: might need to preprocess files using e.g. `file -i`

Answer (score 0):

#### Customize fzf search command

You can pass a `dict` with custom `source` to `fzf` functions:

```
nnoremap <c-p> :call fzf#vim#files('', {'source': g:fzf_project_source})<cr>

let g:fzf_project_source = 'find . \( -name ".hg" -o -name ".git" -o -name "build"
            \ -o -name ".vscode" -o -name ".clangd" \) -prune -o -type f -print'
```

#### Customize fzf action

It's actually not bad to list media files, you can open it with specific program like this:

```
let g:fzf_action = {
      \ 'ctrl-o': '!gio open',
      \ }
```

`gio open` works for me under `ubuntu18.04`, you might need to change it.

There is one edge case you need to know:

- If current buffer is an empty new buffer, `fzf` always open choosen file in `vim` with `e` command.

Not sure if it's a bug.

Comment: Your find command is giving mp4, pdf etc files too in the output.

Comment: @UjjwalGupta  That's just an example to show you how to modify search command, you need to construct the search command by yourself.

Comment: But find command will show the results according to a file name, not by their property. There may be cases when a file has no extension like .txt, .cpp, .py etc but it may be a text file and vice-versa.

Comment: find can do way more than that, check man or info of find.

Comment: An alternative source might be `ack`. It's a grep alternative that processes target dirs recursively and by default only searches file types that are readable (source code, plain text, etc.). You can have it bypass the search part and just list the files it _would_ process with `ack -f`. Just a thought. One way or another you're going to have to define what should be opened since vim opens _everything_.